# JMeter waits unexpectively to execute if statement related to a CSV File

Tags: jmeter

I am running a JMeter Scenario with Apache JMeter 2.11.
The JMeter.bat file contains the following parameterization:

```
set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx12144m
set PERM=-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m

%JM_START% %JM_LAUNCH% %ARGS% %JVM_ARGS% -XX:ThreadStackSize=4096 -jar "%JMETER_BIN%ApacheJMeter.jar" %JMETER_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

I read my data to be executed from a csv file containing the following

[image]

My scenario is defined as below:

[image]

A timer is launched at 29/09/2014 14:32:48

```
<sample t="0" lt="0" ts="1411993968137" s="true" lb="Timer between steps" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Groupe d&apos;unités 1-1" dt="text" by="307"/>
```

"Object Property Page" debug sampler is run at 29/09/2014 14:32:48

```
<sample t="1" lt="0" ts="1411993968370" s="true" lb="object Property Page " rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Groupe d&apos;unités 1-1" dt="text" by="754"/>
```

The debug Sampler "ProppageUpdate Before" is run at 29/09/2014 14:52:16

```
<sample t="0" lt="0" ts="1411995135835" s="true" lb="ProppageUpdate Before" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Groupe d&apos;unités 1-1" dt="text" by="754"/>
```

That is to say 20 minutes after the "Object Property page" debug sampler.
All the requests coming next are executed far close from the "ProppageUpdate Before" debug sampler.

Does this mean the condition "If Property Page" takes time to execute ? 
"If Property Page" is a if statement checking whether "${ObjectType}"=="propage"

Does this mean the csv file parsing is too long ?

We would appreciate any help.

Sylvie

Comment: possible duplicate of [JMeter StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907876/jmeter-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use debug sampler in performance testing , it must be used only when debugging as its name specified.

I wonder , why latency is "0" here and time is too less.Can you add 'view Results Tree' and check the response there [for 'Object Property Page'] ?

Is your CSV file is too huge , what is the size ? how many parameters have you added in his particular CSV ?

Recommendation

1. Split the CSV parameters to multiple csv files , if there are lot of parameters.
2. Check if 'http request sampler' has 'Retrieve all embedded resources'option enabled and 'Follow Redirects' enabled. If both options are enabled , its more likely to see the delay.

check the Jmeter.log[in jmeter/bin dir] for detailed debuging with specifying proper loglevel[default info] in jmeter.properties file.

I would suggest that you set the -Xms and -Xmx to the same values for optimal performance.

example:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Why exactly is setting Xms and Xmx to the same value considered optimal? I'm just curious.